# IBM MobileFirst CLI 7.1 install fail on MacOS

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I just download IBM MobileFirst CLI 7.1 from http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/ 
I clicked install_mac to install but no happen, no install wizard appear. I try right click install_mac to Show Package Contents and click Contents/MacOS/install -> the install wizard appear, I canceled this installation.
Then I try click install_mac again, the install wizard appear, no problem util final step, it show message

```
The installation of IBM MobileFist Platform Command Line Interface is finished, but some warnings occured during the install. Please see the installation log for details.
```

In log tmp

> Install File:
>   /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/__MACOSX/IBMnode/share/doc/._node
>                             Status: SUCCESSFUL
>
> Install File:
>   /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/__MACOSX/IBMnode/share/._doc
>                             Status: SUCCESSFUL
>
> Install File:
>   /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/IBMnode/share/man/man1/node.1
>                             Status: SUCCESSFUL
>
> Install File:
>   /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/__MACOSX/IBMnode/share/man/man1/._node.1
>                             Status: SUCCESSFUL
>
> Install File:
>   /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/__MACOSX/IBMnode/share/man/._man1
>                             Status: SUCCESSFUL
>
> Install File:
>   /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/__MACOSX/IBMnode/share/._man
>                             Status: SUCCESSFUL
>
> Install File:
>   /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/IBMnode/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp
>                             Status: SUCCESSFUL
>
> Install File:
>   /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/__MACOSX/IBMnode/share/systemtap/tapset/._node.stp
>                             Status: SUCCESSFUL
>
> Install File:
>   /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/__MACOSX/IBMnode/share/systemtap/._tapset
>                             Status: SUCCESSFUL
>
> Install File:
>   /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/__MACOSX/IBMnode/share/._systemtap
>                             Status: SUCCESSFUL
>
> Install File:
>   /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/__MACOSX/IBMnode/._share
>                             Status: SUCCESSFUL
>
> Install File:
>   /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/__MACOSX/._IBMnode
>                             Status: SUCCESSFUL
>
> Expand Archive:
>   /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/ibm_node_sdk_mac-x64.zip
>                             Status: SUCCESSFUL
>
> Expand Archive:           /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/null
>                             Status: WARNING
>                             Additional Notes: WARNING - Unknown archive type:
>                                               Could not find file to extract:
>   /private/var/folders/rx/vdt3_jjx39g12lv84xztr84w0000gp/T/AppTranslocation/EC71D510-6F45-4C9F-AC2D-C6E59BADE012/d/resources/mobilefirst-cli-7.1.0-install.zip
>
> Install Directory:        /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/public/
>                             Status: SUCCESSFUL
>
> Copy File:                Destination:
>   /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/public/worklight-ant-builder.jar
>                             Status: WARNING
>                             Additional Notes: WARNING - Source /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/ant-tools/worklight-ant-builder.jar
>   does not exist.
>
> Copy File:                Destination:
>   /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/public/com.ibm.worklight.oauth.tai_1.0.0.jar
>                             Status: WARNING
>                             Additional Notes: WARNING - Source /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight/project/templates/project/externalServerLibraries/com.ibm.worklight.oauth.tai_1.0.0.jar
>   does not exist.
>
> Copy File:                Destination:
>   /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/public/OAuthTai-1.0.mf
>                             Status: WARNING
>                             Additional Notes: WARNING - Source /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight/project/templates/project/externalServerLibraries/OAuthTai-1.0.mf
>   does not exist.
>
> Copy File:                Destination:
>   /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/public/mfp-xs-loader.jar
>                             Status: WARNING
>                             Additional Notes: WARNING - Source /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight/project/templates/project/externalServerLibraries/mfp-xs-loader.jar
>   does not exist.
>
> Copy Folder:              Destination:
>   /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/public/cordova/templates
>                             Status: WARNING
>                             Additional Notes: WARNING - There was a problem copying
>   /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/cordovacmd/cordova/templates/cordova-hello-world-mfp
>
> Custom Action:            com.ibm.lex.lap.ia.LAFiles_IA
>                             Status: SUCCESSFUL
>
> Install Directory:
>   /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/Uninstaller/
>                             Status: SUCCESSFUL
>
> Install Uninstaller:      IBM MobileFirst Platform Command Line
>   Interface(Install All Uninstaller Components)
>                             Status: SUCCESSFUL
>
> Create LaunchAnywhere:    Create
>   Icon:/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/Uninstaller//Uninstall.app
>                             Status: SUCCESSFUL
>
> Install Uninstaller:      IBM MobileFirst Platform Command Line
>   Interface(Install All Uninstaller Components)
>                             Status: SUCCESSFUL

More information 
OS: MacOS High Sierra 10.3 
jdk: javac 1.8.0_151

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Is there a problem using the CLI after installation ?

Comment: Yes, after installation, i check in log file

Comment: There are a few warnings in the log file - but specifically my question is whether you see any problem using the CLI

Comment: I just detail my post, please see, Thanks

Comment: Looks like you haven't understood my question - let me rephrase . What happens when you type the command 'mfp' in a new terminal window after installation ?

Comment: Hi Srik, it throw error, but I just have confirmed from IBM support that they know this issue and they will fix in upcoming release of IBM iFix 7.1. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

New CLI 7.1 just release by IBM to fix this problem

Thanks